# How to copy .mdb file to .mdf file

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, batch-file

I want to copy the ms access database(.mdb) to sql server database(.mdf). I did it with sql server **Import and export data service**. But I want it copy the data regularly or a specific time. Is it possible or not. I have tried to create a batch file

```
copy /y "E:\Dinesh Work\for-reports.mdb" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\for-reports.mdf"
```

but it gives the following error:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I have same tables in my sql server database as msaccess database. Is there any solution with batch file or something else.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. 

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like you want to use the Access database to edit the data in the SQL Server database.
 Is that correct?

If yes, do you really need to **copy** the data?
You could also link from Access to the SQL Server tables.

This way, you have tables in Access that look like normal local Access tables, but they are really just links to SQL Server tables. You can edit data in these tables in Access, but you are actually writing directly into the SQL Server database.

Here are some examples how to set this up:
[Link to SQL Server data](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-to-sql-server-data-HA010200494.aspx#BM2)
[Access to SQL Server: Linking Tables](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/upgrading/accesstosqlserverlinkingtables/1722/)

Answer (score 1):

MDB and MDF files are wildly different types. You can't just copy them.

You might try setting up an SSIS task to do a regular data transfer - something like ETL if you're familiar with that term.

**EDIT**: The reason you're seeing the file locked error is because SQL Server maintains that lock on the MDF file while the database is running. In order to move or copy it you need to take that particular database offline.

Answer (score 1):

As @Yuck said, you can not just copy the file and rename it, you need something like ETL or just a tool to export data.

I did xportdsl to copy from a h2database to a mssql and mssql to oracle 
http://code.google.com/p/xportdsl/

I used gorm and a hacky dsl that worked and it is still working

You can script a bat file to execute something like this java -jar xportdsl.jar test001.txt